# Wordpress footer not showing live but does locally

Tags: php, wordpress, footer

I created a child theme for twenty twelve and added some stuff in there. Now locally it looks fine, the footer is showing up normally.

Though when I added my theme to my server and selected it as a theme the footer is not showing. When I look at the source code the footer is not being loaded.

Now I have my page.php like this;

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" role="main">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
                <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Which is basically the twenty twelve page file. I edited my content file a bit and that is now this;

```
<?php
/**
 * The default template for displaying content
 *
 * Used for both single and index/archive/search.
 */
?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
        <?php if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?>
        <div class="featured-post">
            <?php _e( 'Featured post', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <header class="entry-header">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
            <div class="date"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo get_the_date('d') ?>&nbsp;<?php echo get_the_date('M') ?>&nbsp;'<?php echo get_the_date('y') ?></a></div>
            <?php else : ?>
            <h1 class="entry-title">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                <div class="date"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php echo get_the_date('d') ?>&nbsp;<?php echo get_the_date('M') ?>&nbsp;'<?php echo get_the_date('y') ?></a></div>
            </h1>
            <?php endif; // is_single() ?>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
        <div class="entry-summary">
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
        <?php else : ?>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_content( __( '<span class="readmore">Lees verder <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span></span>', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
            <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentytwelve' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        <?php endif; ?>


    <footer class="post-footer">
        <ul class="post-info-meta">
          <li class="post-info-comment"><div class="post-comment"><?php comments_popup_link( __('0 Reacties','twentytwelve'), __('1 Reactie','twentytwelve'), __('% Reacties','twentytwelve') ); ?></div></li>
        </ul>
    </footer><!-- .post-footer -->  </article><!-- #post -->
```

But as far as I know the footer is called in the page.php and not the content file, correct? Now why is this not showing up? The theme is on http://allesovereline.nl and I don't see any errors that seem to be caused by any of the files I edited either.

These are the errors;

```
[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (www.allesovereline.nl, line 384)
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.ajaxForm')
    wpcf7InitForm (scripts.js, line 14)
    (anonymous function) (scripts.js, line 10)
    c (jquery.js, line 3)
    fireWith (jquery.js, line 3)
    ready (jquery.js, line 3)
    q (jquery.js, line 3)
[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (www.allesovereline.nl, line 384)
[Error] TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.ajaxForm')
    wpcf7InitForm (scripts.js, line 14)
    (anonymous function) (scripts.js, line 10)
    c (jquery.js, line 3)
    fireWith (jquery.js, line 3)
    ready (jquery.js, line 3)
    q (jquery.js, line 3)
```

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening?

What I have tried so far:
Disabling all the plugins.
Selecting Twenty Twelve (works fine, footer is showing there.)
Enabling the error log but it's not making an error file.

Comment: Sadly that's not the problem, tried different browsers, computers and clearing all cache. But thanks for the input.

Comment: From what you've described it sounds like a PHP error. Do you have an error log. The errors you've shown are from the console. What we need to see will be located on the server? If you do have an error log can you include the contents?

Comment: I turned on error reporting in the wp-config file but nothing is showing up on the website.. I realise now that the client said she installed some plugins, I'm asking her to disable them now to see what's happening.

Comment: Can you name the file above that you've modified? Am I correct in believing it's content.php

Comment: Yes it is called content.php

Comment: OK and is it your homepage where the footer doesn't load? If so have you set your homepage to a static page? I'm confused because you make mention of page.php and content.php. In the page.php file the content part being called is content-page.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48372/discussion-between-nathan-dawson-and-kelly)